# Доступ к url в react

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reactjs

На обычной статической странице я использую 3 разных реакт компонента

function renderApp() {

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <ShopList />,   
    document.getElementById("shop-list")
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Filter />,
    document.getElementById("shop-filter")
);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Pagination />,
    document.getElementById("pagination-area")
);
```

}

смысл в следующем: Компонент делает  ajax запрос на сервер, и в качестве параметра передает Категорию. Категорию мне нужно взять из URL. Как это сделать?

URL: /Shop/Category?category=Cameras%20%26%20Photography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let location = document.location;
```

Вернет объект Location, из которого можно получить данные:

```
let paramString = location.search;
```

> Location.search
>      DOMString, содержащий '?' с последующими параметрами URL.

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/location

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Location